# Recommended Menu Sidebar to the Leftside of the Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a menu sidebar.

A button should enable to display or remove the menu. When you feel that you are redo an available button should to show the menu sidebar.

The menu should be located on the left side.

The menu should not affect the remaining component. The menu should be acted independent.

The menu should be located specifically in the webpage when you use vertical scroll.

Today, I have problem to find one. Can you recommend me?

Info:
I'm using jquery and bootstrap

Comment: If this a list of requirements?

Comment: You should maybe go to a site where you pay for people to build things for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [DOWNLOAD Page](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)

And here is the [DEMO](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/)

This library is created with plane `jQuery` and `bootstrap` I used this on some of my projects and so I recommend this to you. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, the left menu affects the remaining component